# Mongoose Update Document or Insert New Document if ID Is Not Found (Express REST API)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I have set up a Express REST Api and would like to Implement a task that checks if a certain Object ID exists.

If that ID exists in the Mongo Database I want to update this Document using a Put Request. This Part already works in my code.

IF the ID does not yet exist in the database I would like to create a new Document. To do this I tried to set the "upsert" option to true, But If I now make a put request to a ID, which isn't in my DB yet it comes back with the error:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "34455ab67" at path "_id" for model "event"
```

Here is my Code for the event model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   }
});
var Events = module.exports = mongoose.model('event', eventSchema, 'event');

module.exports.updateEvent = function (id, event, options, callback) {
   var query = {_id : id};
   var update = {
       name: event.name,
   };
   Events.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, callback);
};
```

This is the REST API Call

```
app.put('/api/event/:_id', function(req, res) {           
   var id = req.params._id;
   var event = req.body;
   var options = {
       upsert: true,
       new: true,
       setDefaultsOnInsert: true
   };
   Events.updateEvent(id, event, options, function(err, event){
       if(err){
           trow err;
       }
       res.json(event);
   })
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The value you are supplying to `id` in the parameter is not valid for conversion to the `ObjectId` type of the `_id` field in the schema, which you are supplying as the query for your statement. So you are either making the call with an incorrect value, or you actually mean to match on another property other than the `_id` field. Your schema only shows `name` and the implied `_id`, so it's possibly just an incorrect value. Can you show the actual database object you expect to update? The other consideration being the schema is wrong and needs a `String` defined for `_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happened because you defined the event schema without "_id",so the type of "_id" property by default become "ObjectId" and then when you tried to send "_id" with this value "34455ab67" mongoose method tried to cast it to "ObjectId" type but it's invalid string. so you should do the following:

1. Send valid string values for the "_id" property.
2. Validate the input string before converting it to "ObjectId".
3. If the input string is valid,convert it to "ObjectId" then use it in 
   the mongoose queries.

Check the following example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//inputId is the input string passed from the front end
if (inputId.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
  // it's a valid string to be converted to "ObjectId"
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(inputId);
  //then use this id in your mongoose queries.
} else {
  //Not valid     
}
```

or you can define the "_id" with "String" type to simplify this process but that depends on your needs.

Comment: The error actually happens because mongoose is already trying to "autocast" to `ObjectId` since that is the defined type for the property which the parameter is being supplied for. Therefore the real cause of the error is that the input "string" is not even valid data to be cast to an `ObjectId`, as is evidenced in the error message. So "explicity" trying to cast will just result in the same error, and therefore does not solve the issue here.

Comment: another point,, we can use simple regex to validate the input string instead of using "ObjectId.isValid" because if found it also accepts string values which don't match the ObjectId format !!
i will update my answer with these updates to be more clearer

Comment: it worked after defining the _id as string in the schema and overriding the object id. thanks a lot